# R Package panelAR not available to install

Tags: r, package, cran, panel-data

I'm trying to install the R package called panelAR in order to perform an autoregressive model AR(1) for a sample of N=17 spanish regions and T=32, but i can't do it. It seems it has been deleted from CRAN. My R version is 4.1.2 btw.

I just wanna know if there is any way of getting the package or a similar one to perform AR models for panel data.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the package from the [archive](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/panelAR/).  Make sure you have installed the `car` package as well as the `panelAR` package depends on it.  Then, you can install the package from the file you downloaded.  Assuming it's in the path Users/yourname/downloads/panelAR_0.1.tar.gz, you can do:

```
install.packages("Users/yourname/downloads/panelAR_0.1.tar.gz", 
                 type= "source", 
                 repos= NULL)
```

I did this and was able to execute the example for the `panelAR()` function.

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin17.0     
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin17.0                  
system         x86_64, darwin17.0          
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          1.1                         
year           2021                        
month          08                          
day            10                          
svn rev        80725                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
nickname       Kick Things
```

The package was archived because it didn't pass some CRAN checks.  Sometimes these are not fatal (as it appears in this situation).  Sometimes they are fatal on some types of systems and not others.  In any event, the package will get archived if the maintainer does not respond with a fix for the errors.